# Estimate Hazard Ratio in SAS for two continuous variables

Tags: sas

I am trying to estimate the point estimates with 2 continuous variables age (age) and tumor size (size). The model I have is survival time (survtime) and death (censdead, censored events = 0). I would like to know the hazard ratio for a person aged at 40 with a tumor size 20 vs the hazard ratio for a person aged at 45 with a tumor size 25. If I use HAZARDRATIO command in SAS such as

```
HAZARDRATIO age / AT (SIZE=(20 25));
```

I get a syntax error, I suspect it's because age is a continuous variable, not a categorical/class variable. The SAS website only provide examples for categorical/class variable.

SAS code:

```
 PROC PHREG Data=abcd;
 MODEL survtime*censdead(0) = age size;
```

Comment: Include the full code and log, especially the error message, the documentation example is continuous that I can see in the latest version so not sure what you're referring to as only categorical variables being referenced.

Comment: I tried code similar to what you posted and it does not generate an error so the error is coming from somewhere else in your code or data.

Answer (score 0):

Your code as posted works fine, your issue is elsewhere.

You can test it by using the VALUNG data set from the [PROC PHREG documentation](https://documentation.sas.com/?cdcId=pgmsascdc&cdcVersion=9.4_3.4&docsetId=statug&docsetTarget=statug_code_phrex3.htm&locale=en)

```
proc phreg data=VALung;
   class Prior(ref='no') Cell(ref='large') Therapy(ref='standard');
   model Time*Status(0) = Kps Duration Age Cell Prior|Therapy;
      hazardratio 'H1' Kps / at (AGE = (45 50)) ;
run;
```

Update your question with your actual code and log and perhaps we can help find the actual issue.